# PyGame Installation Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, pygame, pycharm, osx-yosemite

I downloaded Python 2.7.10 and I wanted to install pygame. I downloaded the DMG from pygame's website (Version 1.9.1) and installed it. To test if pygame was installed properly, I opened IDLE and entered the command `import pygame` just for the following error to return:

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
from pygame.base import * ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

I'm running OSX Yosemite version 10.10.3, does anyone know how to fix this issue and properly install pygame without any issues>

Comment: did you solve this already?

Answer (score 1):

**How to install PyGame on the Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.1**

1. [Install Anaconda 2.7](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_macosx)
2. Get the [SDL Framework](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.3.dmg) run dmg and copy to /Library/Frameworks
3. brew install sdl [note you need Homebrew installed](http://brew.sh)
4. Ensure you have XCODE and latest Command Line Tools for XCODE
5. Open Terminal and run

   `conda update conda`

   `conda create -n py27 python`

   `source activate py27`

   `conda install binstar`

   `conda install anaconda-client`

   `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/erik pyobjc`

   `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/erik pyobjc-core`

   `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/erik pyobjc-framework-Cocoa`

   `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/erik pyobjc-framework-Quartz`

   `conda install numpy`

   `conda install pyopengl`

   `brew install homebrew/python/pygame`

There are some specific instructions to follow after brew is run.

You will also need to create a sitecustomize.py file in /Users/toasteez/anaconda/envs/pygame/lib/python2.7/site-packages

I added the env to my Pycharm Project Interpreter and it seems fine.

Comment: There is an issue with the SDL of which I think happens because Anaconda Python  is 64Bit and SDL may only support 32bit Python

Answer (score 1):

This is the best method I've found for installing on OS X (and works with Python 3):

**Step 1: Install XCode command line tools**

XCode is the tool from Apple for creating Mac and iOS applications. It can be installed from the App Store (it’s free). When it’s finished, type the following at the command line:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

**Step 2: Install Homebrew (http://brew.sh)**

Homebrew is a tool to easily install all kinds of software from the command line. It saves you having to go to a bunch of different sites and download lots of individual installers. Copy and paste this on the command line:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

and follow the directions. You’ll also need to install Homebrew Cask (http://caskroom.io):

```
$ brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
```

**Step 3: Install the rest of the software**

Now we can start installing all the requirements for Pygame. Just type the following commands one at a time and let the computer do its thing:

```
$ brew cask install xquartz

$ brew install python3

$ brew install python

$ brew linkapps python3

$ brew linkapps python

$ brew install git

$ brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_ttf portmidi libogg libvorbis

$ brew install sdl_mixer --with-libvorbis

$ brew tap homebrew/headonly

$ brew install smpeg

$ brew install mercurial

$ pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

**Step 4: See if it works!**

Now we can see if it works. Run Python from the command line:

```
$ python3
```

and try loading Pygame:

```
>>> import pygame
```

If you don’t see an error message, you’re all set!

Comment: I don't want to use Homebrew or Brew.  But thanks for the tip.

Comment: Can I ask why?  Homebrew is a really useful tool and makes it a lot easier to install dev tools and libraries on OS X.  Just curious.

Comment: I just like the Anaconda / Conda Eco system.  It keeps everything in one place.

Comment: Looks like `brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask` doesn't work. It's better to use `brew tap caskroom/cask​​​​​​​`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use on Mac:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

or on other computers:

```
pip install pygame
```